# Repository not being checked

Tags: maven, grails, repository, artifactory

I am running grails 2.4.2 on Windows 7
From BuildConfig.groovy, this is my repositories definition (actual urls replaced with example.com)

```
    repositories {
    inherits true

    switch ( System.getProperty('grails.env')) {
        case ['production']:
            mavenRepo "http://example.com:8080/artifactory/prod-builds"
            break
        default:
            mavenRepo "http://example.com:8080/artifactory/dev-builds"
    }

    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
```

In the plugins section,  I have something like this

```
        compile (':myplugin:[14.08.01,]' ) {
        export = false
    }
```

When I first compile, this works fine.
Later, I have to update the 'myplugin' plugin and change the version to '14.13.01'.
Now when I recompile the plugin that references the myplugin, it doesn't pickup the later version.  If I should make this change:

```
        compile (':myplugin:[14.13.01,]' ) {
        export = false
    }
```

Then I get this error:

> Resolve error obtaining dependencies: No versions available for org.grails.plugins:myplugin:zip:[14.13.01,] within specified range

After poking around, I see that in c:/users/{username}/.m2/repository directory, there is a org\grails\plugins directory that contains the previous myplugin version.  If I delete this directory, then recompile I will get the newest version of my plugin.

So, what do I change in my buildconfig.groovy or my artifactory settings so that grails will search in artifactory for the latest version of a plugin and not just look in my .m2 directory.

Running the clean-all does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for us was to add an updatePolicy to the mavenRepo line.  Like this:

```
mavenRepo "http://example.com:8080/artifactory/dev-builds", { updatePolicy: 'always' }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is SNAPSHOT versions, not version ranges. 
In either way, `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` should help.

Comment: refresh-dependencies does not work.  Using refresh-dependencies does pull in the newest version into my local .m2 directory but grails does not load it.  Grails continues to use the previous version.   Also, these version changes are release versions and so snapshot is not appropriate.